# Login using python requests doesn't work for pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, csrf, pythonanywhere

I am trying login to the site pythonanywhere.com

```
import requests

url='https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login'

s = requests.session()

values = {
    'auth-username': 'username', 
    'auth-password': 'password'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

u = s.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
```

But I am getting a `<Response [403]>` , Csrf verification failed. How do I login to that site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `get` page first.So you can get the `crsftoken` and `sessionid`.And remember to set `Referer=https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/`

```
import requests

url='https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login'

s = requests.session()
s.get(url)

values = {
    'auth-username': 'username', 
    'auth-password': 'password',
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : s.cookies.get("csrftoken"),
    "login_view-current_step" : "auth"
    }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36',
            'Referer': 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/'}

u = s.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
print(u.content)
```