# Python requests: logging into paytm to scrape the merchant data

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, http-post, http-get

I am trying to use the python requests library to login into the paytm and **scrape** the data of paytm merchants from its website by using the paytm nearby. But I am not able to do this, I have a lot of questions like do I need to login or the cookies do the job for me, do I need to put a get request before the post request.

Code I used-

```
payload = {"distance":10,"endLimit":20,"latitude":26.8467088,"longitude":80.9461592,
       "searchFilter":[{"filterType":"SERVICE","value":"PAYMENT_POINT"}],
       "sortBy":{"DISTANCE_WISE_SORT":"ASC"},"startLimit":20,"channel":"web","version":2}
pp = {"method":"get","channel":"web","version":2}
h={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
,'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Connection': 'keep-alive'
         #,'Content-Length': '222'
}

url = 'https://paytm.com/v1/api/getnearbysellers?child_site_id=1&site_id=1'

initial_url = 'https://paytm.com/nearby'

with requests.Session() as session:
    initial_response  = session.get(initial_url)

    response = session.post(url, headers=h, data=payload)


response.text
```

Response i got-

```
{"error":"invalid json","code":400}
```

The things I got by using the network monitoring tool in Chrome

```
General-

Request URL: https://paytm.com/v1/api/getnearbysellers?                                child_site_id=1&site_id=1
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 13.251.31.44:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2018 08:07:10 GMT
Server: openresty
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=66BC9F5E7F355200029AF2316C4E546B; Path=/; secure; HttpOnlyservice/; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-paytm-srv-id: pawslmktshopapp22
X-Powered-By: Express
x-server-time: 1543824430.635
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 2606
Connection: keep-alive

Request Headers-
POST /v1/api/getnearbysellers?child_site_id=1&site_id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: paytm.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 222
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://paytm.com
X-XSRF-TOKEN: LZAiRpku-aptONqCm7Ellab6SEeDAnqZRvuM
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/json
Referer: https://paytm.com/nearby
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: referrer=; secure=true; returning_usr=1; _ga=GA1.2.938904971.1543763520; _gid=GA1.2.1467864151.1543763520; tvc_vid=11543763520802; referrer=; _vwo_uuid_v2=D4CB7C24D54981ADADF33AED06E04E853|54a0ddcfd4724496a7f9ce8ab7cded2a; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vis_opt_test_cookie=1; connect.sid=s%3A__KFlRc2nU_bImjL6OajuBL9cUygnrBi.h1hRCkhz0p5%2FAcoVmArbMXYlUtiv87HJnIueXnr3gSA; _gcl_au=1.1.1598196666.1543771833; _parsely_session={%22sid%22:1%2C%22surl%22:%22https://blog.paytm.com/10-things-you-didnt-know-you-could-do-on-paytm-62a1b200faa6?gi=a3bf13aea45%22%2C%22sref%22:%22https://www.google.co.in/%22%2C%22sts%22:1543823267357%2C%22slts%22:0}; _parsely_visitor={%22id%22:%22pid=a45f5e3ede4fdfe39b8544a91a36ad17%22%2C%22session_count%22:1%2C%22last_session_ts%22:1543823267357}; X-MW-TOKEN=0ac55a86-4b9e-4eaf-8188-71a8c4a705be; X-DM-TOKEN=7f417f58-b33f-4580-a6e3-348f8a324d5c; market-onboard.sid=s%3A8oCGyIrKg-0SsuWTyZ0e6UY3kf89fgnk.SvkZbJub6a%2BG9dZlKMf0rBP80VXFejnCkQiuEdCa27E; AWSELB=97B3358B1C150AC96AC74F39ED34D289809132006F1D0627F111BA7DAB6F4B4A64D171E96C5345A5110C0ECD2E0D82F0BD18BA748DF362808AF3F805565A609A67DC7BF11D; queenoftarts=pawslmktshopapp22; _gat_UA-36768858-14=1; XSRF-TOKEN=LZAiRpku-aptONqCm7Ellab6SEeDAnqZRvuM; _gat=1; _dc_gtm_UA-36768858-14=1; JSESSIONID=9C42AB42BC1AF0240183C02730E3754F


Query String Parameter-

child_site_id=1&site_id=1


Request Payload- 
 {"distance":10,"endLimit":20,"latitude":26.8467088,"longitude":80.9461592,"searchFilter":[{"filterType":"SERVICE","value":"PAYMENT_POINT"}],"sortBy":{"DISTANCE_WISE_SORT":"ASC"},"startLimit":20,"channel":"web","version":2}

Response-
{"requestGuid":null,"orderId":null,"status":"SUCCESS","statusCode":"SS_0001","statusMessage":"Request Successfully fullfilled.","response":[{"cashPointsDetail":{"terminalId":8507407,"terminalType":"User","businessName":"","contactPerson":["Vijay Kumar"],"address":["1","","Aasayana Aasayana"],"state":"Uttar Pradesh","city":"Lucknow","category":"Retail And Shopping","subCategory":"Books","location":{"lat":26.846227,"lon":80.946663},"contactNo":["8587932548"],"displayName":"The Book Service","fax":null,"startTime":"10:00","endTime":"20:00","saturdayStartTime":null,"saturdayEndTime":null,"rating":null,"monday":null,"tuesday":null,"wednesday":null,"thurday":null,"friday":null,"saturday":null,"sunday":null,"landMark":null,"pinCode":"226012","servicesOffered":["PAYMENT_POINT"],"terminalCode":"6283495","establishmentDate":null,"emailId":null,"logoUrl":"https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/pg/Retail%20&%20Shopping.jpg","tagLine":null,"storeId":null,"merchantId":"6283495","address1":"1","address2":"","address3":"Aasayana Aasayana","editAble":true},"currentCashPointStatus":"open","isFavorite":false,"distanceFromLocation":0.07760059905591597,"offerText":null,"dealUrl":null},.........
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to proceed with this problem. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: change to `json=payload`, and it seems you need to login otherwise you will get 403 even though it said `invalid csrf token`.

Comment: I implemented the given code  
`with requests.Session() as session:`      `initial_response  = session.get(initial_url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))  
    h['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = initial_response.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']  
    response = session.post(url, headers=h, json=payload)`

Comment: @kcorlidy  
But I am still getting `'{"error":"Login required.","code":401}'`  

The following code
`from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
sess = requests.Session()
sess.get('https://paytm.com/nearby', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))`  
gives `<Response [200]>`

Comment: You can access `https://paytm.com/nearby`, but it doesnt mean you logged in. I am not sure that you can login with auth. May be you should try to login through login form.

Comment: And i found paytm API. check https://developer.paytm.com/docs/refund-api/ and https://developer.paytm.com/docs/transaction-status-api/

Comment: I am not using the paytm API officially, the APIs mentioned in the previous comment can not get the merchant data. So I am left with the option of making the HTTP request look like as it made through the browser.

Comment: @kcorlidy
I tried to login by using the code provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574908 but I got the `<Response [403]>`

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Different website have different way to login, learning how to use fiddler to watch request structure is very useful. The code below is imitated from browser request. But i cann't make code work perfectly because i dont have an account(even register)

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://paytm.com/v1/api/getnearbysellers?child_site_id=1&site_id=1'

initial_url = 'https://paytm.com/nearby'

auth_code_url = r"https://accounts.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?theme=mp-web&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpaytm.com%2Fv1%2Fapi%2Fauthresponse&is_verification_excluded=false&client_id=paytm-web-secure&type=web_server&scope=paytm&response_type=code"
login_ = "https://accounts.paytm.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=paytm-web-secure&scope=paytm&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://paytm.com/v1/api/authresponse&theme=mp-web&state=null&is_verification_excluded=false&isSignup=true"

with Session() as sess:
    #sess.verify = False
    sess.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/69.0.3494.0 Safari/537.36"
        }
    resp = sess.get(auth_code_url)
    auth_code = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,"lxml").find("div",{"id":"main-container"}).get("ng-init")
    auth_code = re.findall(r"(?<=authState.{4})(.*?)(?=\'|\")",auth_code)[0]
    print(auth_code)
    login_data = {
        "fakeusernameremembered":"",
        "fakepasswordremembered":"",
        "username":"xxxx", #your username
        "password":"xxxx", #your password
        "AUTH_STATE":auth_code

    }
    login = sess.post(login_,data = login_data)
    print(login.text)

    payload = {"distance":10,"endLimit":20,"latitude":26.8467088,"longitude":80.9461592,
       "searchFilter":[{"filterType":"SERVICE","value":"PAYMENT_POINT"}],
       "sortBy":{"DISTANCE_WISE_SORT":"ASC"},"startLimit":20,"channel":"web","version":2}

    resp = sess.get(initial_url)
    print(resp.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'])
    sess.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = resp.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Your code seems to work fine but there is only one issue left that after running this code, paytm sends an OTP for verification. I do not know if this issue can be addressed by python code so that paytm do not send the OTP, during manual login it does not require any verification by OTP. Any thoughts on that will be really appreciable.

Comment: You means when you login through Python, paytm send an OTP to your phone or mailbox? honestly i just only knew the reason is server found you are using script, but i can not figure out what leads to this, because it happened after inputed correct user&password. Btw, you can save cookie to file, and load it from file again when you need.

Comment: It sends the OTP to my phone, the possible reason for the server found out is that the login request is made in no time by the python script.